# Android sql error when using SUM

Tags: android, sql, database, sum

I've run into a problem using an sql query with SUM in it. Im displaying a date and an amount of gram in a listview. Without the SUM it displays the date and gram fine, but it doesnt add up the amount of grams if there are several entries for one date. The SQL query DOES work when i test it in a sqlite database browser. Below is some of my code for this:

```
//attempt 1:
public Cursor getOverviewDate(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{ C_ID, C_DATE, "sum(" + C_GRAM + ")" };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, columns,
      null, null, C_DATE, null, null);

    return cursor;
    }
```

Ive also tried with a rawquery:

```
//attempt 2:    
public Cursor getOverviewDate(){
        String test = "SELECT _id, date, SUM(gram) FROM nutvalues GROUP BY date;";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(test, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

How the query results get outputted:

```
          mySQLiteAdapter = new CalorieCounterDbAdapter(this);
      mySQLiteAdapter.open();

      Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.getOverviewDate();
      startManagingCursor(cursor);

      final String[] columns = { CalorieCounterDbAdapter.C_DATE, CalorieCounterDbAdapter.C_GRAM};
      int[] to = new int[]{R.id.date, R.id.gram};

      SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
       new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, columns, to);

      listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

      mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

I think one of errors displayed in logcat is the key to the solution:

```
 01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'gram' does not exist
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:312)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:87)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at com.korsakopf.caloriecounter.CalorieCounterOverviewActivity.onCreate(CalorieCounterOverviewActivity.java:39)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-07 14:31:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(10497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Ive been searching for a solution for 3 days now. I am an absolute beginner on programming/android so it might just be a nooby mistake but i cant seem to find it.

Comment: First of it says column 'gram' does not exist. Is `CalorieCounterDbAdapter.C_GRAM == "gram"`?

Comment: Does your table has 'gram' column?

Comment: Looks like i managed to solve it. I found it after somebody posted an answer here, but for some reason he removed his answer so my reply comments also got deleted.

Turns out i needed to change the query to:

    `SELECT _id, date, sum(gram) as gram, FROM nutvalues GROUP BY date`

So it was because i did not have have the 'as gram' part in it.

Thx for all the replies!

Comment: Tried it but it wouldnt let me because i do not have enough points :(

Comment: That might be because of [new user restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user). You've been upvoted twice since you last tried, the restriction should be removed now.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i can answer my own question, i couldnt at first because of restrictions :)

Looks like i managed to solve it. I found it after somebody posted an answer here, but for some reason he removed his answer so my reply comments also got deleted. Turns out i needed to change the query to:

`SELECT _id, date, sum(gram) as gram, FROM nutvalues GROUP BY date`

So it was because i did not have have the '`as gram`' part in it.

Thx for all the replies!

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so other can learn from your success.  Cheers~